# Open np.memmap() binary file within a python with-context manager

Tags: python, numpy, errno, numpy-memmap

I have a very strange problem where I can't open a file from one of my larger scripts.

This problem is intermittent and I can't seem to understand the error.
I am getting this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w+') or filename: 'D:\\R4a\\2014_05\\R01359\\R01359_data_dwnhi.dat'
```

from this command in my script:

```
with open(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sonpath,base+'_data_dwnhi.dat')), 'w+') as ff:
   fp = np.memmap(ff, dtype='int16', mode='w+', shape=np.shape(tmp2))
```

when I use:

```
 if os.path.exists(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sonpath,base+'_data_dwnhi.dat')))== True:
    print os.path.normpath(os.path.join(sonpath,base+'_data_dwnhi.dat')) + ' is a file'
```

it evaluates as **`True`**.  Also when I run the `open` command by itself in `ipython` it sucessfully opens the file with:

```
open('D:\\R4a\\2014_05\\R01359\\R01359_data_dwnhi.dat', 'w+')
```

I am at a loss for words and think **`errno 22`** error is misleading.  As I stated earlier, the problem is intermittent and works on some files.  Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

I am working on a windows 8 machine 64 bit and running python version 2.7.8  from an Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit) distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Your opening it like a normal file, hence the error: `IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode`. Do this instead:

```
with open(path, 'wb') as f:
    pass
```

Comment: I have tried `wb`, `w+b` and `w+` modes.  The mode `w+` works on some files while not on others.  And why would it work with `w+` mode when i pass it to the python interpreter?

Comment: Have you really? Your traceback doesn't agree with you. `wb` is for opening in binary mode. There is no point in opening a file in `w+`: the plus symbol doesn't do anything. Have you read the relevant documentation?

Comment: I really have.  I have been trying to debug this for quite some time now and feel someone else might have encountered this problem before.  The mode `w+` opens a file for reading and writing.  As i understand the `+` allows you to override the files content.  It can be found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html).

Comment: I don't know, I certainly haven't run into this behaviour before. Like you, I have high hopes someone will be able to explain this.

Comment: I keep thinking it has something to do with the runtime compiler.  I think thats the only reason it would work in an interpreter and not in my script.

Answer (score 0):

after some trial-errors, instruct **`np.memmap()`** to open a file with other than `.__doc__` reported **`mode`** strings.

```
#------------------------------------------------------++++++++ TRY:
#                                                      ||||||||
#                                                      vvvvvvvv
|>>> MM = np.memmap( "temporary_DATA.memmap", mode = 'wNONSENSE+' )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27.anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\memmap.py", line 208, in __new__
    (valid_filemodes + list(mode_equivalents.keys())))
ValueError: mode must be one of ['r', 'c', 'r+', 'w+', 'readwrite', 'write', 'readonly', 'copyonwrite']
#                                 ^    ^    ^     ^     ^            ^        ^           ^
#                                 |    |    |     |     |            |        |           |
#---------------------------------+----+----+-----+-----+------------+--------+-----------+
```

finally this error Traceback has shown alternative strings, not listed in `np.memmap.__doc__`, which do work fine

```
with open( os.path.normpath( os.path.join( sonpath,
                                           base + '_data_dwnhi.dat'
                                           )
                             ),
           'w+'
           ) as    ff:
   fp = np.memmap( ff, mode  = 'readwrite',      # options listed in np Traceback
                       shape = np.shape( tmp2 ),
                       dtype = 'int16'
                       )
```

---

<sub>For hawkish pythoneers, the post intentionally uses non-PEP-8 source code formatting as it is authors experience that during a learning phase, code read-ability improves the focus on task solution and helps getting used to the underlying concepts rather than to spend efforts on formally adhering typography. Hope the principle of providing help is respected and the non-PEP-8 styling format is forgiven in the name of the ease of reading.</sub>